# Problems in importing self-defined packages and modules?

Tags: python, module, package, project, spyder

I am using Spyder.

I have just started building a project. Its architecture is currently as shown.

[image]

As shown, I have 2 packages, one of which has a module called `trajectorygeneration` now.
Both the `__init__.py` files are automatically generated. I am trying to import the module into the `main.py`, but I ended up with such error messages:

```
>>> from generation import trajectorygeneration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named generation
```

**How may I fix this problem?**

Comment: Spyder (and basically all IDEs for Python) use PYTHONPATH to find libraries. Your likely issue is that you don't have access to these packages in the default search path that Spyder uses to find modules and packages. You need to modify your PYTHONPATH somehow to include the directory that you run your 'main.py' from. This directory includes the package 'generation' which your IDE cannot find. Otherwise you will have to use the regular python interpreter from the same directory as your 'main.py' to run your code properly.

Comment: @ShashankGupta  My current PYTHONPATH is just the directory of my current project. Do I have to do anything about that?

Comment: Hmm if that is the case, then I'm sorry to say that I don't really know why your Python can't find 'generation' module. pythonpath is how most Python IDEs work with finding modules. I don't personally use Spyder though so there could be some different path settings I'm not aware of.

Comment: @ShashankGupta   Thank you for your kindness anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) This is a bug in Spyder. We are not adding the project's path to PYTHONPATH and that's why you can't import your project in the console after you open it. I created an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1554) for you and we'll fix it in our next major release (i.e 2.3).

A workaround for now (as it was mentioned by @Jblasco) is to use our PYTHONPATH manager to add the project's path by yourself. After doing it, you need to open a new console so that changes can take effect.

Comment: Yes, opening a new console is the key!

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that generation is not in your path and python can not find the package?

See: [Expand Python Search Path to Other Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source)

Also, Spyder has a "pythonpath" manager (at least mine has) where you can include any folder in it. Problem is, that if you do it this way, then the python console, for example, will most likely not include those, so you could not import in the console.

Comment: Could you please just tell me what I should do with the "pythonpath" manager?

Comment: In my version, the pythonpath manager is in Tools. When I open it, an empty screen appears. If I hit add path another screen opens. I suggest you choose the folder "clustering" and accept. That will add it to your pythonpath. I stress again, this will only work for spyder, nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I have done the same thing, but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

It seems is caused by typo.

In your picture, target file name is `trajectorygeneration.py`. 
But main.py would import module named `trajectorygeneration's'`.

Comment: I am sorry! The 's' is unintentionally pit there. In the actual run, there is no s as can be seen in the error message. Thnaks for taking itme to see!

Comment: I see that. I'm sorry about that cannot help your problem solving!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness anyway!