# How to install third party modules and libraries through flask web app

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure, flask, pip

I'm trying to install the module mockupbase in order to import HTMLParser for my Flask Web App. Mockupbase is not a package/module within the Python Package Index, so pip install doesn't work in my visual studio development environment. The only resource I could find online about installing third party libraries was http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/, but this link says extensions must be registered under the python package index. I feel like there should be an alternative route to installing third party packages without registering them on python package index. I'm familiar with installing packages on my local computer, but am not sure how to implement this on my flask web project.

**How do I install a third party python module/library not registered on Python Package Index for my flask web application**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that we cannot install module mockupbase on VS using `pip` and `easy_install`.
However, I have ever install custom module as following steps, you can try it.
For example, I create a `Hello.py` file and store it into `C:/Python`  folder. 
Then, I can use it via this method:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:/python')
import hello

hello.hello() # hello,world
```

For this issue, I recommend you refer to this documents:[The module-search-path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)
And you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source).

Comment: Thank you and can you share the steps of implementation in flask web app?

Comment: It is same as the example above. You can try it. Any concern, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify url, local file path, ... instead of package name. By specifying url, file path,  pip will try to download it, unpack it and install it.

According to [Installing Packages - User Guide - pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#installing-packages),

> pip supports installing from PyPI, **version control, local projects,
>   and directly from distribution files**.

If you have multiple packages, you can follow [Fast & Local Installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#fast-local-installs):

> Often, you will want a fast install from local archives, without
>   probing PyPI.
>
> First, download the archives that fulfill your requirements:
>
> ```
> $ pip install --download <DIR> -r requirements.txt
> ```
>
> Then, install using --find-links and --no-index:
>
> ```
> $ pip install --no-index --find-links=[file://]<DIR> -r requirements.txt
> ```