# python + from <module> + how from - import know the PATH

Tags: python, python-2.7

How  the from in python know the PATH of the directory that all module are exists?

For example

Under

```
   /data_py/Python/modulespy
```

I have all the modules as:

```
Df.py
Tr.py
Sw.py
```

So how the following **from** syntax in python know to access the **/data_py/Python/modulespy** folder and read all modules there

```
fromPymoduleeimport*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

This way you can find it out, which all path `python` will look for the modules

***Update as per the comment:***

You can insert your path into the list. Index `0` has the first priority.

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/data-py/modules')
```

Comment: but - if for example I want to build a new module and under other folder as /data-py/modules , then how to import the new module?

Comment: This gives a good overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source