# Why "Unable to bind to Python API"?

Tags: python, module, cygwin

I am trying to work on a lab machine using Python scripts that run fine on my local machine. The scripts were written for Python 2.7, and use the AARDVARK device library as an imported module.

The script runs on Windows' command shell, but fail to run on the installed Cygwin bash shell. The PYTHONPATH variable is defined correctly and similar to my local machine. When running, it complains that it cannot fin the AARDVARK module. So, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3144089/274579), I added the `sys.path.append('/cygdrive/c/aardvark')` command to my script.

Now, when I try running it, I get a pop-up message window saying `Unable to bind Python API. API supports Python 2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7`. Running `python --version` on the bash command line, I get 2.6.7.

What is this error message and how to eliminate it?

How can I make the script run and use the aardvark module?

Comment: cygwin has its own installation of python.  I had issues like this myself. I see you said bash commandline though.

Comment: @TankorSmash - yes, it is running a different python interpreter (2.6) than the one installed on the system (2.7). However, they should be compatible. I am using the Cygwin's bash terminal.