# Proper way of adding module search path on Windows for Python standalone apps?

Tags: python, windows

I am developing a plugin for a multi-platform Python program (Deluge). My plugin needs to import some modules which aren't available by default (in my case, the `requests` module).

On Linux, everything works flawlessly assuming the required modules are installed beforehand (e.g. via `pip`).

On Windows, the program makes use of `python27.dll` which comes as part of the installer, so importing modules - even those available on the local Python installation (verified via interpreter) - yields an import error.

I've seen the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source) question, but I'd like to know if there is a proper way of adding module search paths for Python on Windows specifically. Is it safe to assume `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` will point me to the local Python installation's modules?

**EDIT:** Is there a different method I could incorporate for using "external" modules? Could I perhaps package other modules into my final `.egg` file? Not just plain Python, but more sophisticated modules like `requests` which need to be properly built and may even rely on other modules.

Comment: Print `sys.path` to see where you can add modules.

Comment: Printing `sys.path` from the context of the plugin outputs the standalone Python's `sys.path`, which is mostly files/folders under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Deluge`, mainly `.egg` files. 
If you meant to print the local Python installation's `sys.path`, that would be a good way to locate the `site-packages` folder, but I would need to call the locally installed Python to get its' path locations... Wouldn't that be "messy"?

Comment: No, just look at `sys.path` under Deluge. Is the main application directory or a subdirectory in `sys.path`? Is a zipped library?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Deluge`, and the other paths are `library.zip`, `deluge-1.3.12-py2.7.egg`, and all of the other plugins' `.egg` files under the main Deluge `.egg`. Do you mean that I should somehow add the `requests` module to the Deluge directory?