# Error with importing Numpy in IDLE

Tags: numpy, python-idle

I can import numpy in Geany but it is not possible to import in IDLE and the message is:  `No module named 'numpy'`.

Comment: are you sure the IDLE is the same for python version in the Path

Comment: `numpy` isn''t a standard library module. You need to download it. If it is already on your machine, you need to include enough path information for Python to find it.

Comment: @JohnColeman How to understand the equality of paths and if they are not the same how to fix?

Comment: I suspect that @YasinYousif is right. If you have a version of Python that knows how to find `numpy` (and that seems to be the case from how you phrase your question) then what is probably happening is that you have more than one version of Python on your machine (I have 3), each with their own IDLE, and you are unintentionally using a different version than in `Geany`. IDLE itself has nothing to do with the problem. As far as paths go, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3144089/4996248

Comment: Imports are executed by python, not by Geany and IDLE.  You most likely installed numpy for the version of python used with Geany and not for a different version that you are using to run IDLE.  To fine out, run `import sys; print(sys.version)` in both.  If both responses are the same, add `print(sys.path)` and check where numpy is installed.