# How to import a python file with out of scope dependencies in iPython

Tags: python, import, directory, ipython

Using iPython inside a virtual env (python 2.7.13 and iPython 0.31.1) I am trying to test some code that I have written inside a directory as follows.

```
Root 
  Dir1
   Dir2
     NeedsTesting.py
  Dir3
   Dir4
    Dependency1.py
```

Inside of `NeedsTesting.py` there is an import for `Dependency1`. When I am inside the `Dir2` directory and try to `import NeedsTesting` I get the following error. 
`ImportError: No module named Dependency1`.

When I got back up to root and try `import NeedsTesting.py` the error `ImportError: No Module named NeedsTesting.py`.

When I try and call the file like `from Dir1/Dir2 import NeedsTesting.py` I get a syntax error pointing to the first `/` in the line.

How can I make it so iPython can find modules within an entire project, not just the immediate level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand Python Search Path to Other Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source) help? We need to tell Python which directories to search for modules in.