# How to fix the error "no model named odoo"

Tags: odoo, pytorch

After creating a module, I am ready to create a model and when I put `from odoo import models`, api I see an error `no model named odoo`, could you help me to solve the error please.

I've been searching for possible solutions in Google for a long time and I can not find the solution.

`from odoo import model`, api

Comment: Just give the correct path

Comment: Check you config file of that odoo instance. Seems like that path is incorrect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144107/2102076 Check this answer if it helps