# Module imports from another folder

Tags: python, import, include

I wanted to write a test program and for this I need to include my `DPS310.py` file. But somehow it doesn't work

I tried:

```
• from myPackage import DPS310
• import ..DPS310
• import myPackage.DPS310
```

My structure:

```
Projekt
├── myPackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── DPS310.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_module1.py
├── README.md
├── LICENSE
└── setup.py
```

`test_module1.py` File

```py
import myPackage.DPS310


msg = "Hello World"
print(msg)

dps = DPS310()
#y = DPS310.getTemperature

print(dps.getTemperature())
```

`DPS310.py` File (Extraction. Just to show that the getTemperature method is in here)

```py
...
class DPS310():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.i2c = smbus2.SMBus(1)
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.addr = args[0]
            print("Man addr set")
        else:
            # default sensor's address
            self.addr = 0x77

    def getTemperature(self):
        r = self.i2c.read_i2c_block_data(self.addr, DPS310_TMP_B2, 3)
        # reads out the temperature that is stored in the register
        #       r[0]=TMP0-7    r[1]=TMP8-15  r[2]=TMP16-23
        temp = (r[2] << 16) | (r[1] << 8) | (r[0])  # r[0] << 0
        # deploys this function to 24 bits
        return self.twos_comp(temp, 24)
...
```

If I run the `test_module1.py` file:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
  No module named 'myPackage'
    File "C:\Julian\Projects\PhytonLib_Raspberry\DPS310_Library_RPi\tests\test_module1.py", line 1, in <module>
      import myPackage.DPS310
```

Comment: Try `from Projekt.myPackage import DPS310`

Comment: Same error. Maybe some settings are wrong..

Comment: try to import it explicitly from full path check this link.
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

```
No module named 'myPackage' File
```

Most likely Python doesn't know where to find `myPackage`, so you could try setting it as a [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html) (you could look up the relevant info for your IDE). Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source) StackOverFlow post.

Comment: I also use Pycharm.
okey i have marked **myPackage** as my Source folder. Its blue now.
But the **"import DPS310"** still doesn't work

Comment: Yes. **import myPackage.DPS310**
>File "C:/Users/Schmeizl/PycharmProjects/DPS310-Library-RPi/tests/test_module1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myPackage.DPS310

I tryed this then:
dps = myPackage.DPS310() and 
y = dps.getTemperature()