# PHP Shell Exec Failing to Run Python Script

Tags: python, php

I've been working on a project for school and have been running into some trouble with PHP running python scripts. When I run this specific python script in terminal it works perfectly; however, when I run it through PHP's shell_exec the script fails to display anything. I believe it may be due to captionbot, but I am not sure what the problem really is. (Also when I change my python script to something simple like *print("hello")* it works fine)

Here is the PHP Code

```
echo exec("python /var/www/html/caption.py 'https://www.guidedogs.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/small-boxes-website2.jpg'");

      ?>
```

Here is the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
people = sys.argv[1]
from captionbot import CaptionBot
c = CaptionBot()
desc = c.url_caption(people)
print(desc)
```

Comment: Put `2>&1` at the end of the command, so you see the error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know of that. When I ran it I got "ImportError: No module named captionbot". It looks like the script can't find the module when running through PHP. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: How are you running the PHP script? Are you running it from the terminal or from a webserver?

Comment: You're probably customizing where you look for Python modules, and need to do the same thing for the process that runs the PHP script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source

Comment: I'm running it via a web server and I have not done any customization on where my Python modules are stored. Edit: It seems when I run the script from the terminal it does work, but it does not work on the web server.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of Python on your system, and you're using a different version. Run `python --version` on the terminal and from PHP.

Comment: I just checked and they are both running 2.7.12.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should consider upgrading. Python 2.x was EOL last month.

Comment: What does `env | grep PYTHON` show in your shell?

Comment: I just get nothing when I enter that in my shell.

Comment: Where is the `captionbot` module located?

Comment: It's located in this folder `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas for why it's not finding it from PHP. What does `print(sys.path)` print from PHP?

Comment: For references, see https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Comment: Ok, I finally got it to work. Apparently the folder captionbot was located in was not in the system path for python. I manually copied it over and now it works. I have no idea why python installed the package there but who knows. Thank you so much for your help!