# About the whole process of import in Python

Tags: python

I am new in python programming and I encounter some problem when I use **import** statement.
The following is my directory.

```
package/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    subpackage_a/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        subpackage_b/
            __init__.py
            b.py
```

In `package/main.py` I use `import package.subpackage_a.a` to import `a.py`.
In package/subpackage_a/a.py I try to add `package/subpackage_a/subpackage_b` to PYTHONPATH by modifying `sys.path` in `a.py` and use `import b` to import `b.py`.
However, when I run `package/main.py`, the ModuleNotFoundError appear.
Although changing PYTHONPATH arbitrarily is not a good habit, I still want to know why I can't successfully import `package/subpackage_a/subpackage_b/b.py` by modifying `sys.path` in `package/subpackage_a/a.py` when I run `package/main.py`. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried executing the script using `python -m package.main`

Comment: As it appears, it depends on where you calling it from. You should avoid hacking `sys.path`.  If you call main.py outside package `python package/main.py` your imports should work as the base directory will include package as a module. If you wish to call them inside package, where main.py is then remove `package.` from your imports

Answer (score -1):

Your question may have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source)

to properly add to PYTHONPATH you need to use the absolute path like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/module/')
```