# How to call a shared library (.so file) from a python script?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, shared-libraries, boost-python

I have a shared library `hello_ext.so`. I need to import this shared library in a python script.
The directory is:

```
- project
| - py_binding
  | - hello_ext.cpp
  | - CMakeLists.txt
| - python_script.py
| - CMakeLists.txt
```

The binding is correct and works.

After `cmake ..` and `make` , the library can be called from the `build` folder.

```
$ python3
$ from hello_ext import greet
$ greet()
'hello, world'
```

Therefore the pipeline works.
However, if I run the python script using `python3 /<path_to_sscript>/python_script.py`
I get this **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharad/git_repository/longitudinal_control_pid/py_bindings/arduino_connection_usb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hello_ext import greet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello_ext'
```

I believe the `.so` is not visible from python script.
I am using `cmake` as for the project.

`CMakeLists.txt` under `py_binding` dir:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

set(ThisBinding hello_ext)

find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "")

add_library(${ThisBinding} MODULE hello_ext.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${ThisBinding} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(${ThisBinding} PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

CMakeLists.txt in the major directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

# set the project name
project(longitudinal_control_pid CXX)

# Set some global variables
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(googletest)

file(GLOB SOURCES 
    src/*.cpp
)

file(GLOB HEADERS 
    include/*.h
)

add_library(longitudinal_control_pid ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(longitudinal_control_pid PUBLIC ./)

add_subdirectory(test)
add_subdirectory(py_bindings)
```

I am using Ubuntu `20.04`, `python3`.
I want to make this script import the built shared library and use the bindings.

I have googled this and have not found a solution which worked for me.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the questions. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The shared library needs to be in the module search path of python.

Comment: I am trying to avoid putting .so file in this directory because I would have to do so everytime I change something on the C++ side. Is there a way to include the .so file from the build?
This is possible in `bazel` where I can just make the python target depend on `.so` target.  Is it possible with cmake?

Comment: Python has a thing called search path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source How cmake or bazel could possibly influence that is not something I understand.