# How to run a Python script setting the location of the modules in the shell?

Tags: python, module

I would like to run a Python script setting in the shell where the interpreter must look for the modules.

Suppose that myscript.py contains only:

```
import mymodule ; mymodule.myfunction()
```

But mymodule is in /home/user/hello, whereas myscript.py is, say, in /home/user/Desktop. I want to run on a terminal something like:

$ python /home/user/Desktop/myscript.py LOCATION_OF_THE_MODULES=/home/user/hello.

Would it be possible? I think that an alternative solution is to define the location in the import statement from the code, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to set the location through a variable in the shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand Python Search Path to Other Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source)

Comment: You need to use `argparse` module to parse the command line arguments to set the location to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been exploring a little your question, turns out this isn't a Python question but a "prompt" question, because indeed there is a way to do that but, since Python can't hop into interactive from script, we can't make it using Python only, but the Python interactive command have some extra options we can use
see:

```sh
python3 -h
```

for more info.
Specifically there are 2 options that are interesting, -i and -c which stands for interactive mode and command string respectively, that way we can load the modules with -c and hop into interactive with -i, like so:

```sh
python3 -i -c "import os"
```

Obviously, we need to make it more advanced so it can load multiple modules without Python scripting, then we will be needing to make the actual command to run Python and load the scripts you want, there is a problem tho, since we need to issue a command to be able to load all the modules you want in a folder it might create incompatibilities with prompts since not all prompts have the same syntax. There might be another low-level answer to this problem but I couldn't get to it, however, I will leave a Bash Script for reference so you can use it and/or edit it so it works best with your prompt.

```sh
FINAL_VAR=""
cd $1
for f in *.py; do
    FINAL_VAR+="import ${f%.py}"$'\n'
done
python3 -i -c "$FINAL_VAR"
```

Usage steps:

1. Copy and save the script
2. Give it run permissions (chmod +x file_name.sh)
3. Run it this way: ./file_name.sh "/full/path/to/your/modules"
4. It will load all the .py files and will hop into an interactive Python shell for your use

Note: You might want to change the last line so it works accordingly to your Python installation