# Why undetected_chromedriver module doesn't work? ("No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'")

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, debian, undetected-chromedriver

on Debian 11. In the pip and pip3 packages list, I can see it.
But when I try to run the test script, I get an error:

> root@debian-s-1vcpu-1gb-amd-nyc3-01:~# python3 chromedriver.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "/root/chromedriver.py", line 1, in import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'

```
root@debian-s-1vcpu-1gb-amd-nyc3-01:~# pip3 list
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------------
async-generator         1.10
attrs                   22.2.0
certifi                 2022.12.7
cffi                    1.15.1
charset-normalizer      3.0.1
chromedriver            2.24.1
chromedriver-binary     111.0.5563.41.0
exceptiongroup          1.1.0
ffmpeg                  1.4
h11                     0.14.0
idna                    3.4
lxml                    4.9.2
numpy                   1.24.2
outcome                 1.2.0
pandas                  1.5.3
pip                     23.0.1
pocketsphinx            5.0.0
pycparser               2.21
pydub                   0.25.1
PyPasser                0.0.5
PySocks                 1.7.1
python-dateutil         2.8.2
pytz                    2022.7.1
PyVirtualDisplay        3.0
requests                2.28.2
selenium                4.8.2
setuptools              67.4.0
six                     1.16.0
sniffio                 1.3.0
sortedcontainers        2.4.0
sounddevice             0.4.6
SpeechRecognition       3.9.0
trio                    0.22.0
trio-websocket          0.9.2
undetected-chromedriver 3.4.6
urllib3                 1.26.14
websockets              10.4
wsproto                 1.2.0

root@debian-s-1vcpu-1gb-amd-nyc3-01:~# pip list
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------------
async-generator         1.10
attrs                   22.2.0
certifi                 2022.12.7
cffi                    1.15.1
charset-normalizer      3.0.1
chromedriver            2.24.1
chromedriver-binary     111.0.5563.41.0
exceptiongroup          1.1.0
ffmpeg                  1.4
h11                     0.14.0
idna                    3.4
lxml                    4.9.2
numpy                   1.24.2
outcome                 1.2.0
pandas                  1.5.3
pip                     23.0.1
pocketsphinx            5.0.0
pycparser               2.21
pydub                   0.25.1
PyPasser                0.0.5
PySocks                 1.7.1
python-dateutil         2.8.2
pytz                    2022.7.1
PyVirtualDisplay        3.0
requests                2.28.2
selenium                4.8.2
setuptools              67.4.0
six                     1.16.0
sniffio                 1.3.0
sortedcontainers        2.4.0
sounddevice             0.4.6
SpeechRecognition       3.9.0
trio                    0.22.0
trio-websocket          0.9.2
undetected-chromedriver 3.4.6
urllib3                 1.26.14
websockets              10.4
wsproto                 1.2.0
```

Could you, please, help me to solve this?

I was trying to install udetected_chromedriver on debian, but got error.

my code: python3 chromedriver.py

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python3.x versions installed? Do youhave the same problem with other packages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, For some reason pip was working with python 3.9, when python version was 3.9.2 . Solved the problem with "python -m pip install " Thank you!

Comment: @Michaphp I have the same problem please can you specify more clearly, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried. Same issue, same error..

Answer (score 0):

It may be have been (improperly) installed elsewhere, e.g. with the `--user` switch, which put files into a local user subdirectory (`pip freeze` would show it regardless).

In such case it would be necessary to append this custom user installation subdirectory to the system path (or use any other method to [expand python search path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144107/9962007)).