Direct import fails but "from ... import ..." succeeds
I have a Python module called my_module.py in a folder ~/my_module. I want to call this module from a Python interpreter and I don't know its directory. I run:
import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/my_module"))

import my_module

and it fails. But if I use from ... import ..., then it works:
import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/my_module"))

from my_module import my_module

If I change the folder's name to be different from the module's name, then the direct import works. Why is that?

Do you really want to change directories or is that just to facilitate finding your module? If it is just to find your module, you might add that folder to your search path via something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source

first of all, what is the version of your python interpreter? Python3 introduced namespace packages (I forgot exact version when it happened). This might be a part of your problem. Next, I bet you need to make a better layout of your project. Or if "my_module" is a separate package, it's worth to install it as a dependency for your main package.

@JonSG I want to change directories to find other files in this directory.

@Sergius I have Python 3.12.5. This is a quick layout for students in introductory Python to run a piece of code; could you please tell me your suggestion of a better layout of the project?

@emonigma You can start from https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Files in the folder are not available in the module by default.
When you type import xyz in your code, one of two things can happen:

There's a file xyz.py, then this file will be imported
There's a folder named xyz, then the file __init__.py inside that folder will be imported

Other files than __init__.py aren't imported by default. If you want to keep your file structure like this, you should add a file __init__.py in your my_module folder and put the following content inside it:
from . import my_module

from . means that python will look for the file in your current directory. Then, when calling import my_module in your main file, my_module will have an attribute my_module which holds everything defined in my_module/my_module.py.
(you should think about renaming this...)
However, this only makes sense if the my_module folder is gonna hold multiple submodule files that do their stuff. If it's just one important file, you should not try to import it from the my_module folder, but rather put in one file and then add the folder where that file is to your path using sys.path.append("path/to/whatever"). os.chdir is not the option of choice here.
Please tell me if anything is unclear
